# Can't get custom listener to show up in JMeter's add->Listener menu

Tags: java, jmeter

I've created a custom listener:

```
public class MySQLResultsSaver extends ResultCollector 
implements StatusNotifierCallback, Runnable, TestStateListener {

...
}
```

Using JDK 1.8 locally, in Eclipse and in JMeter 2.13.

I build the listener, export to a jar in C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\MySQLResultsSaver.jar, restart JMeter.

No dice. Nothing in the Add->Listener menu.

Looked at the DEBUG...nothing.

```
"======================"
2015/12/10 12:19:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: search_paths=ApacheJMeter.jar;classes; 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Adding to classpath and loader: ApacheJMeter.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 WARN  - jmeter.JMeter: Can't read classes 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: ClassPath 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: ApacheJMeter.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\bsf-2.4.0.jar 
......

2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\MySQLResultsSaver.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\CMDRunner.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\junit\test.jar 
2015/12/10 12:19:34 DEBUG - jmeter.JMeter: ApacheJMeter.jar 


"======================"
```

Any suggestions?

Joel

Comment: I've looked at forums and the docs, there's no mention of GUI classes, but clearly a listener needs a gui no?

Comment: I suppose you saw this already? https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf

Comment: That is helpful. The ExampleSampler is already farther than I got before. They mentioned the need for a GUI class, and discuss how it's connection to the TestElement. 

I thought I read all the tutorials they shipped. Somehow I missed that one.

Comment: The only one that really matters :P

Comment: Do you intend to publish this listener as a plugin for others to use?

Comment: Just finished a prototype of a sampler writing jdbc. That doc was very helpful. Thanks alot.

Comment: And yes I will consider publishing this once complete.

Comment: I asked about publishing because, if writing to jdbc is all you need, you can do it easily using a jdbc sampler or a beanshell sampler, which would be far easier than writing a whole new listener.

Comment: we want the performance data sample written to JDBC. I thought the JDBC sampler was more about testing JDBC statements (like large SELECTs) within JMeter.

I'll check again

Comment: It is; but nothing stopping you from  running INSERTs to write a bunch of jmeter data to a database either :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a GUI for that listener. The easiest way is to extend `AbstractListenerGui`, i.e.

```
public class MySQLResultsSaverGui extends AbstractListenerGui ...
```

[Here's](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/jakarta-jmeter-2.4/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/gui/SummariserGui.java.shtml) the basic example of such class